# Calabash-Android on WIndows 8 issues

Tags: calabash

We need a quick help. We were trying to automate our Andriod mobile app using calabash. We have grown through all your related tutorials but can't succed in real scenario.

**We did following for our app:**

1. Installed Ruby, Android SDK, JDK, Calabash on Windows 8.
   jdk - jdk-7u51-windows-x64
   RUBY - rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p545
   sdk - fOR 64 BIT
2. Set Environment variables:
   ANDROID_HOME - C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\Calabash\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk
   JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
3. Connected Samsung S3 Andriod device to USB (USB Debugging = Checked)
4. Open eclipse and run Emulator
5. I can see my connected device by running ADB DEVICES command.

**ISSUES:**

A. Though we have JDK installed, we always get "JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT Could not" error message while resigning apk file. How to get rid of this message?

B. Real android device (connected to the USB) is not showing up in the emulator and also in the Android Virtual Device Manager list?

Answer (score 0):

HOW TO INSTALL CALABASH FOR ANDROID IN WINDOWS

Steps to follow:

1. Download Ruby.exe with version less than 2.0 (In this tutorial I am going to use rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p545.exe)
2. Download Ruby Development Kit (For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3)
3. Create a folder called DevKit in  C:\DevKit
4. Extract Ruby Development Kit (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) to C:\DevKit
5. Open command.exe or cmd.exe and type ruby -v to check ruby version(ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32])
6. Now type: cd C:\DevKit and press enter
7. Then type: ruby dk.rb init
8. Then type: ruby dk.rb install
9. Then change to Ruby193 directory by typing: cd C:\Ruby193 on cmd
10. Type: gem install calabash-android
11. Type: gem install calabash-cucumber
12. check by typing: calabash-android version
13. In order to test you *.apk file in calabash you need to re-sign it
    So to make it work you can use two options

Option 1: 
Type: calabash-android resign *.apk and press enter
Type: calabash-android build *.apk and press enter

or

Option 2:
Use a .jar file called re-sign.jar

14. Then create a folder called sample in your desktop and place *_debug.apk. Open cmd then change directory where the *_debug.apk file is found and type: calabash-android gen , to generate the feature files and other associated resources.
15. Last you need to type: calabash-android run *_debug.apk to run the application

Note: To run the application you can use emulator, android device, android screen cast or any related software or devices that allows you to view the process.